# Count up unique occurrences in order

Tags: ms-access

I would like table like this:

```
Cat
Dog
Dog
Phone
Computer
Computer
Computer
```

To look like this:

```
Cat....1
Dog....1
Dog....2
Phone...1
Computer...1
Computer...2
Computer...3
```

This is the Excel Formula that works in EXCEL IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1) that I would like to do in Access.

Comment: I'm not sure this is even possible, even if Access had a row number feature (which it doesn't), because there is no way to order records having the same value.

Comment: Couldn't I order the field by Ascending order first?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: be reassured: this is exactly the problem `ROW_NUMBER()` was invented in Standard SQL to solve i.e. `SELECT thing_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY thing_name, ORDER BY thing_name ) AS tally FROM Things;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got some kind of unique numeric field in there (an autonum would be perfect) you could use:

```
SELECT  Object
        , DCount("ID","Table1","Object='" & Object & "' AND ID<=" & ID) AS Num
FROM    Table1
```

Comment: Note `DCount` is only supported when run using the Access user interface, would cause an error if the SQL query is executed outside the Access UI.

Comment: Good point.  I always assume it is in the Access UI unless they state otherwise.

Comment: Would this go into the field or the criteria. Section

Comment: It's the whole query - select the SQL view rather than the design view when creating a new query and copy/paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

Use a While-Loop with an iteration that resets after every change of record.